# how to dynamically call tooltip on images in MVC 4 razor

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

how to dynamically call tool tip on images in Asp.net MVC 4 razor, i have to show tool tip on images according to package requirement. Please help me how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the attribute on the image dynamically $('image').attr('title','your dynamic title here'); or you can pass dynamic title from contoller to the view in list along with other items in list and set that in the title attribute of image.